# Designing a cancellable operation in WinForms (Save pending changes)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

We are developing a .NET application that uses a few custom controls.

One specific control is a simple "text editor" like control, where some content gets loaded into, based on the user's selection.

In cases where the user modifies the text in this control, and then makes a different selection which would overwrite that content, we would like to have the usual popup saying "Do you want to save pending changes? YES/NO/CANCEL".

I am considering which level of the application should be the one responsible for this: the control itself or the code that uses it?

I have been looking into the existing CancelEventArgs class, and considering using it, however i am not sure if this is a good fit for this specific scenario.

Example code i was thinking of:

When setting the text of the custom control, raise the "BeforeChanged" event. This will be handled and will allow to cancel the operation.

```
public void SetText(string text)
{
    CancelEventArgs args = new CancelEventArgs();

    // Raise the BeforeTextChanged event.
    BeforeTextChanged(args);

    // If the user cancelled the operation - do not modify text.
    // For example, user code will check if needs saving, show the popup, etc.
    if (args.Cancel)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the data being bound to the control?  Are you manually populating it from within your UI Form or is there an internal binding in your control which handles the the database call/update?

Comment: There's no data binding. The control is basically a big textbox that accepts text from the user. I also keep a flag to monitor if the data is "dirty" (needs saving) or not. When navigating away/replacing the text, i would like to check that it is saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to handle this with events - it will just complicate matters.  This is linear problem and a dialog popup will halt the current thread and give you enough control to handle the user's decision.  The event in this scenario is the 'UserSelectionChanged' event.  No need for more.

Answer (score 1):

It looks ok in both cases but to keep your logic consistent; In case, you have encapsulated the file loading/contexts loading inside the user control then keep the use events. otherwise, handle it on the target form/control.